# How to add email as activity in opportunity through Web API

Tags: c#, acumatica

I was trying to add email message into an opportunity as one of the activites using web api and the following is the code I tried:

```
            CR304000Content CR304000 = context.CR304000GetSchema();
            context.CR304000Clear();

            List<Command> cmds = new List<Command>();

            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = opportunity.ID, LinkedCommand = CR304000.OpportunitySummary.OpportunityID, Commit = true });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Draft", LinkedCommand = CR304000.Activities.MailStatus});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = "Email", LinkedCommand = CR304000.Activities.Type});
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = email.Subject, LinkedCommand = CR304000.Activities.Summary });
            cmds.Add(new Value { Value = email.Message, LinkedCommand = CR304000.Activities.NoteText });

            cmds.Add(CR304000.Actions.Save);
```

The code didn't give me error, however, after I run the code, I got a "note" ,instead of email, added into "Activities" under that opportunity.

Can somebody give me some clues of adding email (draft) into an opportunity as an activity? Since I could manually go to "organization" -> "customer management" -> "opportunity" and click on "Activities" tab and then click "Add Email" button to add email(draft) to opportunity, I assume I should be able to do the same thing through web api...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code snippet to add Email Draft to existing opportunity.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
//Opportunity Screen
CR304000Content CR304000 = context.CR304000GetSchema();
context.CR304000Clear();

//Email Activity Screen
CR306015Content CR306015 = context.CR306015GetSchema();
context.CR306015Clear();

//Locate Opportunity for which Email Draft needs to be added
CR304000Content[] CR304000result = context.CR304000Submit(
    new Command[]
    {                                        
        new Value { Value = "000007", LinkedCommand = CR304000.OpportunitySummary.OpportunityID, Commit = true},
        //Invoke New Email Actity Action
        CR304000.Actions.NewMailActivity
    });

//Specify data for Email Activity
CR306015Content[] CR306015result = context.CR306015Submit(
    new Command[] 
        {                    
            new Value { Value = "Subject 7", LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.Subject },
            new Value { Value = "Notes Addition 7", LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message_.ActivityDetails},
            CR306015.Actions.Save
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, however, I couldn't figure out how to add CR306015 to my web service list...there is only "opportunity" under "Organization"->"Customer Communication"...do you know how can I add this API to my wsdl through "Systems"->""Integration"->"web service"?

Comment: @Gladiator, you can find CR306015 in Company -> Hidden as Email Activity.

Comment: I tried your code but got "PX.Data.PXException: Error #13: Inserting  'Activity' record raised one or more errors. Please review. Error: 'From' may not be empty", and I couldn't find "from" field in web service specification, although I tried all fields that look like "from" such as: new Value { Value = email.FromAddress, LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.FromMailAccountID }, new Value { Value = email.FromAddress, LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.FromEmailAccountID }, and new Value { Value = email.FromAddress, LinkedCommand = CR306015.Message.FromMailFrom }, either of which worked.